# Xml lookup tables

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0

I am attempting to use a lookup table in xml for an xsl transformation. I am familiar with xsl and not concerned with the physical loading and querying of a lookup table, rather I'm having trouble formulating an appropriate XPath with a sparsely populated lookup.

I will be using a table that will require fallback to default values if the lookup attribute is missing. The following xml is an example of this population:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<codes>
    <code id="12" country="ca" areacode="420" division="45"/>
    <code id="13" country="ca" areacode="519" division="45"/>
    <code id="14" country="ca" areacode="519" division="40"/>
    <code id="15" country="ca" division="46"/>
    <code id="16" country="ca"/>
    <code id="17" country="au"/>
    <code id="18" country="au" division="32"/>
</codes>
```

When doing the lookup I will have input for country, area code and division to find the appropriate id.

I've tried a couple of options but none of them are satisfactory. The XPath below will return two entries (I should get the id of 15):

```
/codes/code[@country='ca' and (@areacode='222' or empty(@areacode)) and (@division='46' or empty(@division))]/@id
```

XPath 2.0 is supported in my xsl.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly then `@country` always exists so we can do a key based lookup on that attribute. For the other two attributes `@areacode` and `@division` you want take the `code` which has both attributes matching with priority over a `code` which has one matching attribute with priority over a `code` with no matching attribute.

So I would simply create a sequence of the different priorities and take first one found:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="lkp-url" select="'test2013062402.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lkp-doc" select="doc($lkp-url)"/>

<xsl:key name="by-country"
         match="code"
         use="@country"/>

<xsl:param name="c" select="'ca'"/>
<xsl:param name="ac" select="'222'"/>
<xsl:param name="d" select="'46'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="(key('by-country', $c, $lkp-doc)[@areacode = $ac and @division = $d],
                        key('by-country', $c, $lkp-doc)[not(@areacode) and @division = $d],
                        key('by-country', $c, $lkp-doc)[@areacode = $ac and not(@division)],
                        key('by-country', $c, $lkp-doc)[not(@areacode) and not(@division)])[1]/@id"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know which of the two attributes has priority, you might want to shuffle the second and third item in the sequence I created in the code if `areacode` has priority.

The above code should be shortened to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="lkp-url" select="'test2013062402.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="lkp-doc" select="doc($lkp-url)"/>

<xsl:key name="by-country"
         match="code"
         use="@country"/>

<xsl:param name="c" select="'ca'"/>
<xsl:param name="ac" select="'222'"/>
<xsl:param name="d" select="'46'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="cs" select="key('by-country', $c, $lkp-doc)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="($cs[@areacode = $ac and @division = $d],
                        $cs[not(@areacode) and @division = $d],
                        $cs[@areacode = $ac and not(@division)],
                        $cs[not(@areacode) and not(@division)])[1]/@id"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on testing against my real life scenario it works beautifully. I'll be adding this to my personal XSL tips Wiki!